# convert an array with object into array with 2 objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I'd like to create a new Array (myArrayFruitSelect ) when I select (for example "apple") in a menu a Fruit.

```
MyArray [{ fruit: "Apple", value1: 89, value2: 2.6 },{ fruit: "Banana", value1: 59, value2: 3.6 },{ fruit: "Orange", value1: 49, value2: 5.6 }...etc]

var selectFruit = document.getElementById('FiltreFruits').value;

var myArrayFruitSelect = _(_.where(rows,  { fruit: selectFruit}));
```

I'd like to have this result :

```
myArrayFruitSelect[{ fruit: "Apple", value1: 89},{ fruit: "Apple", value2: 2.6}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` method and add new object for each `value` property where `fruit` value is equal to `selectFruit` value.

```js
const array =  [{ fruit: "Apple", value1: 89, value2: 2.6 },{ fruit: "Banana", value1: 59, value2: 3.6 },{ fruit: "Orange", value1: 49, value2: 5.6 }]

var selectFruit = document.getElementById('FiltreFruits').value;
const result = array.reduce((r, {fruit, value1, value2}) => {
  if(fruit == selectFruit) r.push({fruit, value1}, {fruit, value2})
  return r;
}, [])
console.log(result)
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Apple" id="FiltreFruits">
```

If you want more dynamic solution without hard-coding keys you can use `forEach` loop inside `reduce`.

```js
const array =  [{ fruit: "Apple", value1: 89, value2: 2.6 },{ fruit: "Banana", value1: 59, value2: 3.6 },{ fruit: "Orange", value1: 49, value2: 5.6 }]

var selectFruit = document.getElementById('FiltreFruits').value;
const result = array.reduce((r, {fruit, ...rest}) => {
  if(fruit == selectFruit) Object.keys(rest).forEach(key => r.push({fruit, [key]: rest[key]}))
  return r;
}, [])
console.log(result)
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Apple" id="FiltreFruits">
```

Comment: my problem is not to filter. I 'd like to convert my result into an array with 2 objects